# Create a SQL select query dynamically at runtime

Tags: sql

I have a requirement where I need to write a SQL select query with dynamic columns at runtime. There are few mandatory and optional fields in the DB. I want to generate the query at runtime based on the values present in the incoming request.

Ex:  DB has colms A,B,C,D,E
scenario 1: request has only value for A, query should be generated as

```
select * from table where A='<somevalue>'
```

scenario 2 . Request has value for A and D , query should be generated as

```
select * from table where A='<somevalue>' and D='<somevalue>'
```

Currently it is being handled using java to create string for not null values and appending it to select statement to form the final query.

Ex:

```
if (A!=null) 
  String query_a='<somevalue>'
else 
  query_a=""
```

and then appending `<query_a> <query_b>` to form final query

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: In Java or in SQL? Because you only have the SQL tag, but in the question you do not mention you want to remove it from Java.

Answer (score 2):

In your SQL script, you can better parametrize like below. I've assume that you are using parameters.

***It's basically sql idea.*

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE (
   (@p1 IS NULL OR columnA = @p1)
OR (@p2 IS NULL OR columnB = @p2)
OR (@p3 IS NULL OR columnC = @p3)
OR (@p4 IS NULL OR columnD = @p4)
)
```

Comment: Based on the example of `select * from table where A='<somevalue>' and D='<somevalue>'`, the "main" `OR` logic might be rather `AND`. Otherwise wouldn't it generate a suboptimal query plan for maybe all scenarios?

Comment: Simplify as `(columnA = @p1 or @p1 IS NULL)` etc.

Comment: Definitely right @DávidLaczkó that is the other performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider doing this construction of queries in Java, creating an appropriate [Prepared Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for each case.

```
List<String> clauses = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
clauses.add("1=1");
if (you_want_to_search_on_column_a) {
   clauses.Add("column_a = ?");
   params.Add(value_to_search_on_column_a);
}
if (you_want_to_search_on_column_b) {
   clauses.Add("column_b = ?");
   params.Add(value_to_search_on_column_b);
}
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " + String.join(" AND ", clauses);
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(queryString);
for (int i = 0; i < params.size; i++ ) {
   stmt.setString(i+1, params.get(i));
}
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

This way you'll present queries with exactly the filtering criteria you need, and so give MySQL's query planner the best possible shot at optimizing each one.

If you were working with Oracle or SQL server it would be worth your trouble to keep a cache of PreparedStatement objects, but that's not so with MySQL.